# Не понятно поведение функции-конструктора

Tags: javascript

```
function MyArray() { }
MyArray.prototype = [];

var arr = new MyArray();
arr.push(1, 2, 3);
alert(arr.length);
```

Почему в переменной arr ссылка на массив? `var arr = new MyArray()` - это же создание нового объекта. Или это из-за того что `arr.push(1, 2, 3);` и то что в прототипе массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вкратце:** за всем стоит свойство "***prototype***"

**Не вкратце:**
Вызов метода ***push***, сначала ссылается на новый объект **arr**. После того как метод **arr**.***push*** не будет обнаружен, ссылается на свойство ***prototype*** функции-конструктора **MyArray**, а свойство ***prototype***, в свою очередь, определяет что будут наследовать новые объекты, т.е: в данном случае "**[ ]**" *(массив)*.
Если вы нарочно создадите метод ***push*** в новом объекте **arr**, то ссылки на прототип не произойдёт.

Ссылка на прототип как раз таки создается оператором **new**, во время создания нового объекта.

Comment: Спасибо, за разъяснение.

Answer (score 1):

> `var arr = new MyArray()` - это же создание нового объекта

В JS почти все является объектами ( кроме примитивов, да и те при необходимости, обертываются в функцию соответствующего конструктора, иначе откуда берутся методы у чисел?)
Если вас сильно беспокоит, то: `typeof arr // "object"`
В вашем случае, вы правильно думаете, все из-за свойства **prototype**